# importing module with name of variable from another script?

Tags: python, import

`current_code = dsajJasndfD` is in second file also. I need to import it by using local current_code (it will be changing after every program restart).

So here is my question: How can I import module, when I don't know its, but have it name assigned as local variable?

```
current_code = dsajJasndfD
import database as db
key_list = list(db.current_code.keys())
value_list = list(db.current_code.values())
```

Comment: Shouldn't `dsajJasndfD` be string? Do i get it ok, that it's the name of the other file - the package to be imported?

Comment: If I understand, you need import a module named `dsajJasndfD`?

Comment: `importlib` is the module you are looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131217/error-handling-when-importing-modules
The second answer there can serve you the solution for your problem.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
current_code = "foo.py"
__import__(current_code)
```